# Embed PDF in Mac OS (Safari)

Tags: html, macos, pdf

I have a web page that embeds a PDF from an absolute URL.

I am using this code, setting the data type as per this [information](http://joliclic.free.fr/html/object-tag/en/object-application.xhtml#pdf).;

```
<object id="pdf-preview" data="http://mysite.com/myPDF.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="430" height="280">
    alt : <a id="pdf-preview-alt" href="http://mysite.com/myPDF.pdf" title="Download">PDF link</a>
</object>
```

This is working fine on Windows (Firefox,Chrome), but falls over on Mac OS (Safari, Firefox), displaying just the alt text/link.

Any ideas?